# How to store state client side for chained micro services

Tags: microservices, state, stateless-session

I'd like to store microservice state client side.  For a `single service` it seems fairly straight forward how to achieve this (return an `attribute` in the `HTTP body` for the state).  However things get more complicated with chained services.

[image]

In the example above both `API2` & `API3` hold state I want to return to the client.  I'm wondering how this is best achieved.  My current thinking is `API1` exposes a **single** state `attribute` to the client.  `API1` is then responsible for adding any state returned from `API2` or `API3` into that state attribute.

I'm wondering if there are any other options people have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregation of data on API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316573/aggregation-of-data-on-api-gateway)